# Using Powershell class in C++ application

Tags: c++, powershell, c++-cli, clr, redistributable

The CLR option(compile with `/clr`) is necessary to use the managed code(ie. Powershell class) in unmanaged C++ code.

A sample code is as follows:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::ObjectModel;
using namespace System::Management::Automation;

int main() {
    PowerShell^ ps = PowerShell::Create();
    ps->AddScript("Get-ChildItem C:\\");
    ps->Invoke();

    return 0;
}
```

After writing a code, I noticed that the compile option `/MT` and `/CLR` are incompatible. Then, I knew that the redistributable package is necessary to support the various executing environment.

Is there any solution not using redistributable package?

Is there any solution which enables to embed Powershell script in C++ application?

Comment: It's an identity problem -- in .NET, the identity of a type depends on the assembly where it is declared.  If it were possible to statically link the runtime into your EXE, it would change its identity and cease to be compatible with types already used in API surfaces.